# C++ Code not building with build project (F6) in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

I have a large solution that contains C# and C++ projects. After I code in my classes or functions I run a build to have the parser check syntax. What I have noticed is that when I press F6 the entire solution will build and get parsed except for the C++ files that I'm working on.

This seems like it's not the intended function of the editor so is there a way I can force this to happen when I perform a build?

Thanks,

P.S. I know I can go to rebuild project and force a build that way. I'm looking for a way to have the editors treatment of C++ and C# files be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the solution properties, under "Configuration Properties", make sure the C++ projects are set to build.  Also, make sure the project dependencies are setup properly.

These two things control which projects are built when you run a build.

Comment: The project was not set to build.